# Navigation menu keeps pushing down elements when opened. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**important note** before I even ask the question: It was much shorter and simpler for me (therefore you too) to just show the CSS part regarding media queried, because it would be too much useless code/info otherwise. Meaning - please resize your browser to the size mentioned in CSS (width 480px or less) to see what I'm talking about. And no I'm not using bootstrap for this...

**My question is next:** How am I supposed to make my "hamburger" menu overlay the content (opened onclick) and not push it down? 
Even better if it can be done without any JS but remember, sliding effects or easing in/out - not stuff im looking for. 

Here is the snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else {
        x.style.display =  "block";
    }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .networks, .sidenav, .image-row, .foot1, .foot3 {
    display: none;
    }
    
    body {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    }
    
    .page-wrap {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    }
    
    .logoImg {
    width: 200%;
    }
    
    .menuIcon {
 display: inline-block;
    float: right;
 width: 10%;
    margin-top: 6%;
 margin-right: 5.5%;
    border: none;
    z-index: 3;
    }

    .navButton {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border: none;
    z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .navButton:focus {
    outline: none;
    }
    
    #menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
    z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .main {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 7.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .textbox {
 display: block;
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: justify;
    }
    
    .myPhoto {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .foot2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #324B64;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, 
                   initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    
    <title>Luka Novak</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
        
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            
        </div>
        <div class="networks">
            <a href="#"><img src="facebook-symbol.svg" class="socialnet" alt="facebook"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="instagram-symbol.svg" class="socialnet" alt="instagram"></a>
        </div>
            <div class="menuIcon">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="navButton">
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-toolbar/512/menu-512.png" 
                     alt="menu" 
                     class="iconImg">
            </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sidenav col-5" id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="navlink">about us</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">services</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main col-18">
        
        <article class="textbox">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </article>
        
        <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image1">
            
            </div>
                
            <div class="image2">
                    
            </div>
                
            <div class="image3">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="footer col-24">
        <p class="foot1">Some info</p>
        <p class="foot2">design by me</p>
        <p class="foot3">More info</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
    
</body>    

</html>
```

And in case that the snippet looks weird (as in jsfiddle, plus not registering menu being clickable at all), here is CodePen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxmMrJ 

(remember to resize the window in codepen too)

Comment: Are you aware that your menu breaks when you make the screensize small (480px), then open and close the menu, and make the screensize bigger again? The menu will disappear when you go back to a bigger screensize. You might want to look into that ;)

Comment: @SirExotic I'm not sure what do you mean by that menu breaking. Code snippet here in my question isnt working properly anyway, but codepen link should be all right without such breaks when opening/closing and resizing...

Comment: Oh wow, now i know what you meant and I'm seriously confused. Since i doubt that it has any relation to JS, i suppose it's related to CSS :after property? Any advices about that fix?

Comment: I think it is the javascript code. But I'm having a hard time reading all of your code to find it. My honest advice would be some navigation bar tutorial videos to get the hang of it. Did you see my answer to your question, by the way?

Comment: I just posted an answer here on my own question to say thanks to you guys who answered and solved the problem. It worked perfectly when changed following your advice. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Could you also mark the answer that helped you most? And if you have any further questions that are different from this one, it is best to create a new question.

Comment: Already tried to vote but since i'm a newbie to StackOverflow i only get a message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." when placing a vote...:/

Comment: There is another icon under the voting that marks the answer as the "solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your position from relative to absolute on the menu id and and change the margin-top to maybe 20%; this should move the menu on top of your information.

Cheers Mate.

Comment: Yep, the result is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much! :) <br>
if you can spare a few more minutes to look at this problem that SirExotic pointed out, about menu disappearing i'd appreciate it even more

Answer (score 0):

Check this code pen [link](https://codepen.io/gautamnaik1994/pen/JvbOrd)

When you click the button, make its position absolute.This way, it will not interfere with the opened menu.

Add this to your css

```
.menu-button-enable{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 4;

}
```

Add this to js

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    var mButton = document.querySelector(".menuIcon");
   if (x.style.display === "block") {
       x.style.display = "none";
     mButton.classList.remove("menu-button-enable");

   } 
   else {
       x.style.display =  "block";
     mButton.classList.add("menu-button-enable");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to layer content on top of each other is by given it the `position: absolute;`. With that, and some positioning, you can position your menu on top of your content, like so:

[image]

Just replace this with the `#menu` rule in your media-query for 480px and it will work :)

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
```